# Check If Stripe Customer Was Charged Upon Creation

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So I have two ways I am creating charges in Stripe in PHP, one when I create a customer object, the other when I just use the charge object.

The latter is working perfectly, the former is breaking when I check if the customer was charged, which should happen right away because I subscribe said customer to a plan.

Here is the code that works:

```
    try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example charge",
  "amount" => $amount,
  "receipt_email" => $email,
 "currency" => "usd")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
if ($charge->paid == true)
{
  save_stripe_customer_id($token,$amount, $today, $type, $email);
   echo "Thank you for your donation!";
}
```

Notice the `$charge->paid == true` which is what I am checking for. I want to use this same property when creating and charging a customer, but it doesn't seem to have this method when I do this:

```
try {
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "description" => "Customer for APCAN",
  "source" => $token,
  "plan" => $plan,
  "quantity" => $amount,
  "email" => $email
  ));
}catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined or something
}
if ($customer->paid == true)
{
  save_stripe_customer_id($customer->id,$amount, $today, $type, $email);
  echo "Thank you for your donation!";
}
```

Notice a similar code, `$customer->paid == true` but it doesn't fire. I see the charge go through in the dashboard when the customer gets created this way, but I don't get the proper `echo` back and the function `save_stripe_customer_id()` doesn't fire.

So how do I check if the customer created that way and charged using the plan was actually successfully charged?

Answer (score 1):

The Stripe `Customer` object does not have a `paid` attribute you can check like the `Charge` object. Instead, when you create a customer and subscribe them to a plan using the Stripe API, Stripe will make sure the credit card is valid and able to be charged before returning. See Stripe doc here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions

I believe the actual `Invoice` for the subscription is created but not necessarily charged right away. As per Stripe's doc here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoices

> Once an invoice is created, payment is automatically attempted. Note that the payment, while automatic, does not happen exactly at the time of invoice creation. If you have configured webhooks, the invoice will wait until one hour after the last webhook is successfully sent (or the last webhook times out after failing).

I also recommend contacting Stripe Support directly with any questions as they are very quick to respond in my experience, and have been helpful in the past.

Comment: You can also query the customers charges, as subscriptions create charges when ran.